# Slide in animation in android

Tags: android

I have a question about how to set two views in layout with first view on the screen and second view off-screen, and when the first view is clicked, I want to make the second view slides in and overlay on top of the first view. What I have tried is the following.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="FirstView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="FirstView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

With this view, I have set up the slide in animation and it worked fine only if I set the width of the first and second view less than the parent. (ex. first view width = "100dp" and second view width = "100p"). The problem is when I set the width of both views as match_parent, the animation did not work. How do I solve this? or is there an alternative layout for this?

Comment: Could you post your animation code?

Comment: @shhp is it necessary? The code just changes x-coordinate using Facebook Rebound Spring System.. What I think the problem here is the second RelativeLayout that is being placed right to the first view seems not inflated..